# How to add and delete data into a MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, mysqli

I would like to add / delete information into my database using PHP at a certain area. What I mean is that I have an array of courses that the user has selected and I would like to combine this array to the courses that I have in my database. I would like to do the same thing except instead of adding courses its deleting. I though about using CONCAT, but I can't figure out how to use it in my code.

My php file looks like this:

```js
<?php
include("account.php");
//connect to MySQL database
session_start();
$dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL database");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
$adchoice = $_POST['adlist'];
$user = $_POST['name'];
$num = $_POST['number'];
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM StudentDB WHERE StudentName = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$user) ."' AND StudentID = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$num) ."'" ;
 $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 1) 
 {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH))
  {
   print "Originial Courses:";
   echo '<br />'.'Student Name: ' . $row['StudentName'] . '| Student E-Mail: ' . $row['E-Mail'] .';'. '| Student ID: ' . $row['StudentID'] . '| Student Courses: ' . $row['Student Courses'] .'<br />';
  }
 }
 if ($adchoice == '3')
 {
  echo "User: " .$user .'<br />';
  print "You have chosen to add classes<br>"; 
 }
 if ($adchoice == '4')
 {
  echo "User: " .$user .'<br />';
  print "You have chosen to drop classes<br>"; 
 }
 foreach ($_POST['classes'] as $select)
 {
  echo "You have selected : " .$select .'<br />'; // Displaying Selected Value
 }
  if ($adchoice == '3')
 { 
  //add the classes to the db here
 }  
 if ($adchoice == '4')
 {
  //delete the classes in the db here
 }
}
else
{
 echo "ERROR<br>";
}
?>
```

As for the courses that will be selected it look like this:

```html
   <select name ="classes[]" multiple>';
   <option value = CS332>{cs 332}</option>";
   <option value = CS241>{cs 241}</option>";
   <option value = MATH333>{Math 333}</option>";
   <option value = ECON201>{Econ 201}</option>";
   <option value = PHYS111>{Phys 111}</option>";
   <option value = CS114>{cs 114}</option>";
   <option value = MATH337>{Math 337}</option>";
   <option value = STS201>{STS 201}</option>";
   </select>
```

I have no idea how to combine the array with the items in the database that is located under Student Courses for that specific student without erasing everything with UPDATE, same for deleting. To reinstate the question : **I need help in combining an array with the data already located in my database and I need help in using an array to delete data that is located in the database without erasing everything there.**

Example :

For adding: if array looks like this: `classes[] = cs 113 , cs 114, cs 332` and the courses in my database are `cs 364 , cs 213 , cs 202` I want the result to be `cs 113 , cs 114, cs 332, cs 364 , cs 213 , cs 202`

For deleting: if array looks like this: `classes[] = cs 113 , cs 114, cs 332` and the courses in my database are `cs 113 , cs 114 , cs 202` I want the result to be `cs 202`

```html
             <TD>
    <select id = "myListAD" name = "adlist" >
               <option value = "3" >Add</option>
      <option value = "4" >Drop</option>
             </select>
   </TD>
```

The User will select beforehand whether they want to add or drop classes and the array that they create will be based off that decision.
Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: The user will decide to add or drop courses. For adding: Combine an array( that the user created by selecting courses) with a database that has courses already included in the Student Course Column ( like CS332 CS280 IT202 MATH333). From my understanding using UPDATE would result in the courses being replaced with the array instead of combining together. As for deleting (selected drop option): if a class the user selected matches a class they have then the class will be deleted from the database if not then nothing will happen.

Comment: do you use multiple delete option

Comment: I'm new to PHP, so I don't know if multiple delete option is some method or not. If its not a method then the array that the user created for adding will be used for deleting. At the start the user is able to select whether they want to add classes or drop classes. If they choose drop classes then the array will be created for the purpose of using it to remove classes from the database. Which is were the issue is being that I don't know how to delete multiple specific classes from the database. As for adding I don't know how to combine the array and the classes in the database.

Comment: Doyou use teamviewer

Comment: No, but I don't want anyone to access my device. Gives me a weird feeling.

Comment: Ok. any web site

Comment: I don't use any sites like that.